# Elementary number theory contest problem: USAMO 2004/2

Tags: contest-math, infinite-descent

Here is a problem from the 2004 USA Math Olympiad.

> Suppose that $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are integers whose greatest common divisor is $1$. Let $S$ be a set of integers with the following properties: (i) For $i=1,\dots,n$, $a_i\in S$. (ii) For $i,j=1,\dots,n$ (not necessarily distinct), $a_i-a_j\in S$. (iii) For any integers $x,y\in S$, if $x+y\in S$, then $x-y\in S$. Prove that $S$ must equal the set of all integers.

The solution my book provides first says that if $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ are some integers that "generate" $S$ and satisfy the three conditions in the problem statement, then $b_i-2b_j$ and $2b_i-b_j$ are in $S$ for any indices $i$ and $j$. This part of the argument is easy to follow and just directly uses the three properties.

However, the solution then goes on to say

> An $n$-tuple $(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n)$ as above can be substituted by $(b_1,b_2-b_1,\dots,b_n-b_1)$, which again generates $S$ and, by what we just proved, satisfies (i), (ii), and (iii).

This, I do not understand. Why is it the case that the new $n$-tuple generates the same $S$? In particular, the elements $b_2,b_3,\dots,b_n$ must be in the $S$ generated by the new $n$-tuple (since they are in the $S$ generated by the original $n$-tuple $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$) but I am not sure how they are. Some clarification here would help.

Comment: Can you link to the solution? $\quad$ The approach I ultimately took to solve this problem was to show that $ \sum n_i a_i \in S$ by induction (twice, and had to be careful). This clearly implies what you need (but the way you expressed the solution suggests that they intended the step to be obvious/immediate).

Comment: @CalvinLin, this solution is presented in *Putnam and Beyond*. You can find it on page 249 here: https://mathematicalolympiads.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/putnam-and-beyond.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(b_1, b_2, \ldots ) = S$ and $ (b_1, b_2-b_1, \ldots , b_n-b_1) = T$. WTS $ S = T$.

Consider $T$:

- by (ii), $b_1 - b_1 = 0 \in T$
- by (ii), $ (b_i - b_1 ) - b_1 =  b_i - 2b_1 \in T$
- $0, b_1, 0+b_1 \in T$ so by (iii), $0 - b_1 = -b_1 \in T$.
- $ b_i - b_1, -b_1,  (b_i-b_1) + (-b_1) \in T$, so by (iii), $(b_i - b_1) - ( - b_1 ) = b_i  \in T$.

Comment: Why is it the case that if $x,y\in S$ then $x-y\in S$? (ii) only implies that this holds for $x,y\in\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}$, not arbitrary $x,y\in S$.

Comment: @AndrewPaul Oh, you have a good point. That would explain why this problem is much harder than how I wrote it up.

Comment: @AndrewPaul This should work now?

Comment: That looks correct, thanks!